# menu button with list when hovered over and nested menu

Tags: html, css

I have created a button (lets call it Menu button) that has 3 lines on it to symbolise a menu. When the user hovers over it displays a list. Up to here the code is doing what I want. It was showing the two buttons however when I give each button a nested list the display goes all funny. Here is my [fiddle so far](https://jsfiddle.net/umebyshd/27/)

What I want is when the menu button is hovered over it displays two further buttons (or I guess can just be list items), one button called Region and one called Export. When either of these are hovered over I would like them to display a list to the side of themselves.

**HTML**

```
  <div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">
  <div class="navbar">
  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="two"></div>
  <div class="three"></div>
</div>
  </button> 
  <div class="dropdown-content">
<ul>
  <li>
      <button class="dropbtn" value="Region">
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <ul>
          <li>Japan</li>
          <li>South America</li>
          <li>Europe</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
  </li>
  <li>
      <button class="dropbtn" value="Export">
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <ul>
          <li>Excel</li>
          <li>CSV</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
  * {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
 }

 body {
  background-color: lightblue;
 }

 .navbar {
   width: 50%;
   display: block;
   margin: 50px auto;
   padding: 8px 10px;
   transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
 }

  .navbar div {
    height: 5px !important;
    background: #fff;
    margin: 7px 0px 7px 0px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  }

  .two {
   width: 35px;
   }

   .three {
   width: 50px;
   }

   .navbar:hover div {
   width: 60px;
   }


  .dropdown {
   position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
  }

 .dropbtn {
   background-color: #9FACEC;
   color: white;
   padding: 16px;
   font-size: 16px;
   border: none;
 }

 .dropbtnLi {
    background-color: #9FACEC;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
  }


  .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
   }

   .dropdown-content li {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
   }

   .dropdown-content li:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

   .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

   .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #4C66E9;}
```

Comment: try making a snippet next time i think then some one could help u better

Comment: @AKASHPANDEY sorry want do you mean by a snippet?

Comment: got the js fiddle working on it i missed the js fiddle you mentioned my bad

Answer (score 1):

> On hovering you need to display them separately, i.e. when hovering
>   the main button, display only the sub-buttons. And when you hover the
>   sub-buttons then you can display the list.

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

/* vertical threline nav bar */

.navbar {
  width: 50%;
  display: block;
  margin: 50px auto;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.navbar div {
  height: 5px !important;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 7px 0px 7px 0px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.two {
  width: 35px;
}

.three {
  width: 50px;
}

.navbar:hover div {
  width: 60px;
}



.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropbtn {
    background-color: #9FACEC;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
}

.dropbtnLi {
    background-color: #9FACEC;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
}


.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content li {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content li:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #4C66E9;}

.dropdown-content-list {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown-content-list:hover {
  display: block !important;
}

.dropdown-content-li:hover .dropdown-content-list {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  background: #efefef;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">
    <div class="navbar">
      <div class="one"></div>
      <div class="two"></div>
      <div class="three"></div>
    </div>
  </button> 
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <ul>
      <li class="dropdown-content-li">
          <button class="dropbtn" value="Region">Country</button>
          <div class="dropdown-content-list">
            <ul>
              <li>Japan</li>
              <li>South America</li>
              <li>Europe</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown-content-li">
      <button class="dropbtn">Export</button>
          <div class="dropdown-content-list">
            <ul>
              <li>Excel</li>
              <li>CSV</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is working code.

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

/* vertical threline nav bar */

.navbar {
  width: 50%;
  display: block;
  margin: 50px auto;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.navbar div {
  height: 5px !important;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 7px 0px 7px 0px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.two {
  width: 35px;
}

.three {
  width: 50px;
}

.navbar:hover div {
  width: 60px;
}



.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropbtn {
    background-color: #9FACEC;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
}

.dropbtnLi {
    background-color: #9FACEC;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
}


.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content li {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content li:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover > .dropdown-content {display: block;}

/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #4C66E9;}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">
    <div class="navbar">
      <div class="one"></div>
      <div class="two"></div>
      <div class="three"></div>
    </div>
  </button> 
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <ul>
      <li>
          <button class="dropbtn" value="Region">
          <div class="dropdown-content">
            <ul>
              <li>Japan</li>
              <li>South America</li>
              <li>Europe</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
      </li>
      <li>
          <button class="dropbtn">
          <div class="dropdown-content">
            <ul>
              <li>Excel</li>
              <li>CSV</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or you can set direct child for hovering on parent li. like `.dropdown:hover > .dropdown-content {display: block;}`